# Crystal Reports ASP.NET Export PDF as Multiple Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I use CR to export PDF file according to parameters I send from my ASP.NET Web Forms application. In the current situation, I can export one page PDF but I want to add more pages with different info. 
Current situation: [When I export PDF from my ASP.NET app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YC2ez.png) 
What I try to achieve: [Different Pages with different information but same format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZLak.png)

In summary, I am trying to add pages in the for loop, is that possible to add different pages in the same format?

My CR report: [CR report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pY1qz.png)

My code in ASP.NET Web Forms application:
(dt datatable in the code is actually have more rows but I couldn't find how to show each record in seperate page in the example above)

```
ReportDocument reportDocument = new ReportDocument();
        reportDocument.Load(Server.MapPath(@"Report\MyReportFile.rpt"));


        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = new DummyDL().PROCEDURE_GET_DUMMY_DATA(DUMMY_NO);


        reportDocument.SetParameterValue("P_DUMMY", DUMMY);
        reportDocument.SetParameterValue("P_DUMMY1", Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["DUMMY1"]));
        reportDocument.SetParameterValue("P_DUMMY2", Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["DUMMY2"]));
        reportDocument.SetParameterValue("P_DUMMY3", Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["DUMMY3"]));


        PrintOptions printOptions = reportDocument.PrintOptions;


        ExportOptions exportOpts = new ExportOptions();
        PdfFormatOptions pdfOpts = ExportOptions.CreatePdfFormatOptions();

        exportOpts.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
        exportOpts.ExportFormatOptions = pdfOpts;
        
        reportDocument.ExportToHttpResponse(exportOpts, Response,false, "");

        if (!IsPostBack) CrystalReportViewer1.Error += new ErrorEventHandler(CrystalReportViewer1_Error);
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportDocument;
        CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the data for the other pages to the data source.

For example, if you are limiting the data to one order by passing a parameter of OrderID and applying a record selection based on that parameter, change the parameter to allow multiple values.

Comment: I am totally new in CR, I couldn't understand how to achieve that. I edited my question and added my CR report and my code in c#, can you help me more about how to achieve this? I think I have to add new page for each record in my datatable but how?

Comment: and I changed Allow Multiple Values to "true" but then how can I show each record(from my datatable or list in asp.net) in seperate page?

Comment: Crystal reports would show all the data (unless you filter/suppress data).
If you want each record/group to start on a new page, the section properties allow you to  start a new page before/after each record/group.

Focus on creating a report that shows all the data/pages you wish. Do this in the report designer interface. 

If you don't know how to do certain things, there are many YouTube tutorials for Crystal Reports.